# Mouse cursor disappears in Ubuntu 13.04 under VMware

Tags: 13.04, gnome, mouse, cursor

Why does the mouse cursor disappear on the desktop in Unity or GNOME under 13.04 running in a Virtual Machine (VMware Fusion on a Mac in my case)?

All I did was upgrade to 13.04 ... I've been using Ubuntu for a number of years (and VMware Fusion) and I've never seen such a persistent problem.

I tried :

- Reinstalling VMware Tools
- gnome-tweak-tool
- unity-tweak-tool
- Creating a new userid
- Loading Kubuntu desktop
- dpkg-reconfigure xorg and dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Nothing worked.

Comment: Please don't write the *answer* into the *question*! You are able to create a new answer and post the content there.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution written by OP inside the question:*

> Finally I used "Gnome Fallback" as my desktop manager and all of a
>   sudden I got a cursor.
>
> This works for me now, although I would really like to try using the
>   new KDE desktop as well as Unity.
>
> It appears to me to be a problem with compiz (perhaps) or at least has
>   something to do with the VMWARE XORG drivers as they interact with
>   13.04 (my guess).
>
> Hope this helps someone else out .. maybe someone can figure it out
>   from here.